# Deleted_Flg and Effective End Date in Soft Delete

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, datamodel, snowflake-schema

I have implemented soft delete in warehouse and added an attribute called deleted_flg in the table and values would be 0 = Not Deleted, 1 = Deleted.

However i was thinking of another approach of keeping an attribute called effective_end_date which would be populated with the date incase of record is deleted and Null if record is active.

Should I keep both the attribute or only one of them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need, really, to implement soft delete in more than one way, you should decide which of those approaches suits you best and go forward with it, still remembering that instead of a DELETE you are making an UPDATE action, which has its own additional checks and tasks, such as maintaining referential integrity, changing some of the views etc.